# How many monitors and at what resolution can I use with a Toshiba Tecra a50-EC?

Tags: toshiba

I have looked through the manual for my laptop and I cannot seem to find any information that specifies how many external monitors and at what resolution I can use...

Comment: Count output graphic ports

Comment: @gaspsf so I know I can use at least two monitors but it is unclear at what resolution I can use two monitors.

Comment: Cant find anything useful. My guess is 1920x1080. Better figure out it practically or ask manufacturer. Cant even find its site. Manual tells nothing.